# git with jpeg image files remain on remote git repo after changing jpeg files?

Tags: git, gitlab

I did git push ( push to remote git repo) but later I realised thatI had to change jpeg images to much smaller size. After I changed jpeg images to much smaller size I did git add . followed by git commit followed by git push. My question does the remote repository (gitlab) still keeps old jpeg images? As for as I know for source code files it keeps the differences in code files so that in case we want to revert back to the old version, it can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question does the remote repository (gitlab) still keeps old jpeg images?

Yes, meaning the overall size of the Git repository would not be smaller because you pushed smaller images: binaries are not stored in delta.

You would need to do a filter-branch or a BFG ([BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)) in order to remove older (and bigger) jpeg files.
And then force push the result (since the SHA1 of past rewritten commits would have changed). So make sure you are the only one working on that repo, or that you alert your colleagues *before* force pushing your local rewritten (and smaller) repo.